# Unable to decrypt a file securely from external file location and move it to a Safehouse in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sftp

I need some help with SFTP set up that I'm working on in Automation Studio. The issue I have an I'm trying to resolve is how to avoid exposing decrypted CSV file on the FTP Import folder and instead decrypt the file to a Safehouse first before importing in to MC?

Here is some context: I have File Transfer Activity that will pick up a file from external FTP (I use FileZilla) and decrypt PGP file using Private Key. The File action is set to 'Manage File' then on Configuration the 'Source File Location' is set to the standart 'ExactTarget Enhanced FTP'. The next step is 'Import File' activity that will look at the same file location and pick up the decrypted .csv file based on specific file name pattern and import the data into Sendable Data Extension.

I've being trying to play with the setting but on the File Transfer Activity I can only specify the source file location and not where exactly I want to file to be decrypted. My understanding is that once the File Transfer Activity processes a file (like decrypting it), the processed file is automatically placed in the Safehouse. Also while I don't have direct access to the Safehouse (like I do with the Enhanced FTP/Import folder), Marketing Cloud automations are designed to work with it seamlessly so when setting up the Import Activity, I should be able to select the file from the Safehouse as the source but when I do that I'm getting an error 'File Not found' as it's being decrypted on the FTP/Import folder.

Do I miss something here? Is there additional functionality that needs to be enabled by Support? If someone has experienced this I will appreciate if you share your thoughts. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can ask SF Support to enable your account the "Delete file from ET FTP or Safehouse" Extract Type in the Data Extract Activity. Once done you would be able to place Data Extract Activity in your automation after File Transfer Decryption or maybe Import File Activity to delete the files by the new descrypted "File Naming Pattern" from the SFTP, thus barely exposing decrypted files.

Here is how it looks when creating a Deletion Data Extract in the Properties tab -
[image: Deletion Data Exract - Properites tab]

and that is the configuration tab -
[image: Deletion Data Exract - Confirguration tab]

you can select to delete the file from the Import / Export / Safehouse options (File Locations do not work here).

Comment: Thank you but the goal here is to move the files to Safehouse not deleting them as by the time they get deleted they will be exposed as well. Looks like the Safehouse wasn't enabled to the account that's why I couldn't access it. I though that this should be there by default. However, it should be enabled by SF Support. I will keep in mind the "Delete file from ET FTP or Safehouse" Extract Type in the Data Extract Activity as I wasn't aware that you can do that either. Could be useful for another use case. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Safehouse wasn't enabled to the account that's why I couldn't access it. I though that this should be there by default. However, it should be enabled by SF Support.